# Out of Memory Exception in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers

Tags: linq, model-view-controller, out-of-memory

I have an MVC 5 site running in a shared hosting environment.  It uses Linq to Sql for data access. About 5-8 times a day it experiences an "Out of Memory Exception" in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers. The problem occurs on different requests and is intermittent. It appears to be happening early in the controller method when the system is looking up a single record in a single table.  Hosting provider does not seem able to help. Error report follows:

An application error has occurred in ClaytonBocce.org

### ** Application Information **

Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/119/ROOT-1-131413223158297977
Trust level: Full
Application Virtual Path: /
Application Path: D:\inetpub\claytonbocce\
Machine name: WEBA36

### ** Events **

Event code: 3005
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
Event time: 6/7/2017 10:20:34 AM
Event time (UTC): 6/7/2017 5:20:34 PM
Event ID: f643ddd5511449fba679c11b0e67d562
Event sequence: 152
Event occurrence: 1
Event detail code: 0

Process information:
    Process ID: 1012212
    Process name: w3wp.exe
    Account name: WEBA36\IUSR_216.119.96.82

Exception information:
    Exception type: System.OutOfMemoryException
    Exception message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Request information:
    Request URL: https://www.claytonbocce.org:443/League/Match/4612/281
    Request path: /League/Match/4612/281
    User host address: 66.234.194.42
    User: 
    Is authenticated: False
    Authentication Type: 
    Thread account name: WEBA36\IUSR_216.119.96.82

Thread information:
    Thread ID: 340
    Thread account name: WEBA36\IUSR_216.119.96.82
    Is impersonating: False
    Stack trace:    at

```
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IRuntimeMethodInfo method)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Compile(SqlExpression expression, Type elementType)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.GetReaderFactory(SqlNode node, Type elemType)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at BocceData.Model.BocceWork.get_CurrentSeason() in D:\Users\dev\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ClaytonBocce\BocceData\Model\BocceActive.cs:line 15
   at BocceData.Model.BocceWork.SetSeason(Int32 sid) in D:\Users\dev\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ClaytonBocce\BocceData\Model\BocceActive.cs:line 37
   at BocceData.Model.BocceWork.GoToSeason(Int32 sid, Boolean requireTeam) in D:\Users\dev\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ClaytonBocce\BocceData\Model\BocceActive.cs:line 66
   at BocceData.Model.BocceWork.set_ActiveValue(String value) in D:\Users\dev\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ClaytonBocce\BocceData\Model\BocceActive.cs:line 119
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive(Int32 filterIndex)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__31(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

---

Here is the code that calls LINQ in this failure. Line 15 is the first line of the get. BocceSeasons is a LINQ to SQL table. But this is not the only failure location; the memory exception is thrown in different locations and not consistently in any one location in the application, but always in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod.

```
public BocceSeason CurrentSeason
    {
        get
        {
            BocceSeason sn = BocceSeasons.OrderByDescending(s => s.id).FirstOrDefault(s => s.IsCurrent);
            if (sn == null) throw new ApplicationException("BocceActive: No current season found");
            return sn;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is there at line: 'BocceActive.cs:line 15' & 'BocceActive.cs:line 119
' ? May be posting some code should help to understand.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the error dump, in your BocceWork class there's a `CurrentSeason` property which executes some LINQ2SQL code that's causing the problem.

Comment: Dennis Mitchell, did you ever find a solution to this issue?  We are running into it as well.

Comment: We are still experiencing this problem. It appears to occur in runs lasting several minutes.